# android - get light level every ten 10 minutes

Tags: android, timer, listener, sensors, light

My app needs to have an updated light level value (a 10-15 minute delay is fine or something) (this is not a commercial app) within its background service....

I know how to retrieve the light value using a SensorEventListener and the SensorManager but in the API docs it says explicitly that if you don't unregister the listener when you don't need it it will drain your battery in just a few hours.

now my question is....how can I use the listener along with the sensor manager to retrieve a light level value every 10-15 minutes?

Could I use something like the below with a Timer that runs this task every 10-15 minutes?

```
    private TimerTask lightSensorTimer  = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (sensorManager != null)  {

            Sensor lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

            if (lightSensor != null) {

                sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                while (newLightLevel == lightLevel) {
                    try {

                        **Thread.sleep(1000);**

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Interrupted exception in lightsensor timer: " + e.getMessage());

                    }
                }
                PhoneEvents.this.lightLevel = PhoneEvents.this.newLightLevel;

                sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorListener, lightSensor);
            }
        }

    }

};
```

The sensoreventlistener does nothing but this:

```
    private SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {

            PhoneEvents.this.newLightLevel = event.values[0];

        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

    }

};
```

I'm not even sure if you can use Thread.sleep within a timer task. But I have ready that TimerTasks need to finish quickly otherwise they batch up.

Is there a cleaner solution for something like this?

Thanks

Regards, 
Andreas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an alarm that calls a serviceIntent.

Start the alarm every 15 minutes:

```
    AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i=new Intent(this, YourService.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
```

and your service looks like this:

```
public class YourServiceextends IntentService {
    public YourService() {
        super("YourService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have a service as foreground service. So I don't need to wake-up the device every 15 minutes. so you're saying to use the alarm manager within my foreground service?

Comment: No. Don't use a foreground service and only start your service when you need it via an alarm.

Comment: Well, I don't know really what your service does. I think that you should use an alarm for an intent, and to keep it all neat, why not make a separate service for this task. It doesn't matter if something else is also running I guess. So I think above code would still be good. Just handle your stuff in the onHandleIntent.  (hmm, @falmarri was quicker :D.. but that ;)  )

Comment: @falmarri but that's not what I asked.

Comment: @Nanne, ok If I make a separate service that gets called every 15 minutes...the onSensorChanged function might not be called before the service finishes. that is the point i'm trying to make in the question

Comment: You asked for something cleaner, this is it. You certainly don't want to use sleep. The proposed service can send somthing (an intent, some content, a broadcast etc) so anything else you've got can react to it.

Comment: @Nanne yes it is indeed cleaner and thanks for that. my question in the first place should be: how can i guarantee that when I register the sensoreventlistener's onSensorChange method is called in the service that is started by the alarm manager?